# lager powerd erlang application crash when start

Tags: logging, erlang

What does this error message mean?

```
Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-39-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 13 18:33:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

2013-12-13 14:36:38 =ERROR REPORT====
** gen_event handler {lager_file_backend,"log/console.log"} crashed.
** Was installed in lager_event
** Last event was: =
    {log,{lager_msg,[],
            [{pid,<0.6.0>}],
            info,
            {["2013",45,"12",45,"13"],["14",58,"36",58,"38",46,"753"]},
            {1386,916598,753876},
            [65,112,112,108,105,99,97,116,105,111,110,32,"lager",32,115,
             116,97,114,116,101,100,32,111,110,32,110,111,100,101,32,
             "gateway_proxy@ubuntu"]}}
** When handler state == 
   {state,"log/console.log",
       {mask,127},
       {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.2242>,11}},
       940277,false,10485760,
       [{hour,0}],
       5,lager_default_formatter,[],
       {mask,15},
       1000,1000,65536,
       {1386,916598,672037}}
** Reason == 
    {'function not exported',[{timer,now_diff,
             [{1386,916598,753876},{1386,916598,672037}],
             []},    
              {lager_file_backend,write,4,
                          [{file,"src/lager_file_backend.erl"},{line,187}]},
              {lager_file_backend,handle_event,2,
                          [{file,"src/lager_file_backend.erl"},{line,141}]},
              {gen_event,server_update,4,
                         [{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,504}]},
              {gen_event,server_notify,4,
                         [{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,486}]},
              {gen_event,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,248}]},
              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                        [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}
```

Comment: I would advise to upgrade up to more recent Erlang release, say R16B02 or R16B03, if it's ok for you. And check if the problem persists.

Comment: `{'function not exported',[{timer,now_diff,[{1386,916598,753876},{1386,916598,672037}],[]}` - that's strange, the `timer` module is part of stdlib... It's hard to see how it could be missing.

Comment: I update erlang to R16B02,but problem still there

Comment: Try doing `m(timer).` in the shell and see what functions are exported.

Comment: @rvirding now_diff/2 is exported from timer module and i have wrote a test to verify it

Comment: Hmm, is everything running on the same machine? Though it is hard to understand how anything could run with stdlib. You are not running a release which only loads parts of kernel and stdlib? Just thinking out loud really.